# CSS horizontal list not shown horizontal in firefox on chrome

Tags: css

Hi i'm trying to create a toolbar using ul and li elements, everything works good on IE8 but when i render the page in google chrome o firefox the elementos does not show in horizontal way. Here is the css i'm using for the toolbar.

```
div.Toolbar
{
    padding: 4px;
}

div.Toolbar ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.Toolbar ul li a, div.leftMenu ul li a:visited
{
    border: 1px solid #f0f5f8;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}

div.Toolbar ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

div.Toolbar ul li a:active
{
    border: 1px solid #f0f5f8;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}


<div class="Toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNuevaOrden" runat="server" Visible="False">
                <img runat="server" id="img12" border="0" src="~/images/icons/action_add.gif" />
                Nuevo Registro
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </li>

        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCambiarContrasena" runat="server" Visible="False" CausesValidation="False">
                <img runat="server" id="img11" src="~/images/icons/login.gif" border="0" />
                Cambiar Contraseña
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a screen shot or a link?

Comment: I agree with Chip Hunt, you need to either 'float:left' the li elements or make them 'display:inline' or 'display:inline-block'. But also remove some weird css: 'a:hover text-decoration:none; padding-right:5px; float:left;' make no sense, as they are already in the a class just above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have your `li` elements float, not the `a` elements.

Original (actually works as expected on Firefox and Chrome for me): http://jsfiddle.net/56ESk/
New: http://jsfiddle.net/56ESk/1/

You also don't need to repeat already accounted for declarations in your `:hover`

```
div.Toolbar
{
    padding: 4px;
}

div.Toolbar ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.Toolbar ul li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

div.Toolbar ul li a, div.leftMenu ul li a:visited
{
    border: 1px solid #f0f5f8;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* float: left; */
}

div.Toolbar ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div.Toolbar ul li
{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This works fine too, although N.B. that inline formatting is generally more restrictive (it's difficult to add vertical margins or padding, for one), and you have to be up to speed with positioning inline elements with block elements, which may not be something you want to worry about right now.